# How do I list the contents of an Android APK file programmatically?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I need a list of all the files stored in a given APK file.  I am using the NDK.

Challenges:

- Get the path to the .APK file on the device.
- Iterate through all of the files, recursing through the subdirectories.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to treat the apk file as if they are zip files.
Since you're working within NDK, you can try using a C++ library like [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) to help you browse through the zip file entries.

Comment: Just fyi, if you want to do this Java at some point, there are existing zip utility API in the standard library.

Comment: Is there anyone with experience using candidate libraries who would like to chime in?  I see zziplib as another possible choice.

Comment: This question may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883564/android-how-to-make-native-zip-application

Answer (score 0):

For the first part of your question, the path to the .apk on the device, refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507960/does-android-keep-the-apk-files-if-so-where) (it's on StackOverflow, so I won't bother recopying it).

For the second part your question, unzipping an .apk file on the device, download the source for [Terminal IDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.spartacusrex.spartacuside) (Terminal IDE also works on non-rooted devices). Download its source from the [download](https://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/downloads/list) tab, not the browse source tab (which for some reason doesn't work right now).

It's a huge project mostly in Java (it's not exactly the language you're looking for), but it's well organized and remarkably readable.